# Standard text (non code-specific) filetypes in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, what are some possible `filetype`s that can be used for writing standard text -- I suppose occasionally with code, but more geared towards notes and miscellaneous. The only one that I've come across that seems acceptable is `ft=markdown`, but I'm sure there might be others as well that might be a better fit. What are some other possible filetypes that can be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for various text-based markup languages, there are a couple options:

- Markdown (`markdown`), which is probably the most popular but is designed primarily for HTML;
- AsciiDoc (`asciidoc`), which can convert to DocBook, HTML, PDF, and more;
- Pod (`pod`), which is used mainly by Perl and converts to various formats;
- reStructuredText (`rst`), which is more common among Python projects;
- Org (requires an extension), which is commonly used on Emacs, but can also be used on Vim.

There are of course many more, but these are probably the most common.

If you're looking for a format that is just for notes and you're not going to convert it into anything else (or only going to convert it into HTML), then any of them are fine.  If you're looking for broader conversion capabilities, then AsciiDoc (using Asciidoctor) or reStructuredText are better choices.

Comment: great, thank you. It seems for my colorschemes/indentations, markdown and asciidoc both work great out of the box, with the edge going to ascii. Thanks!